# Wrong CSqlDataProvider sorting attributes text

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15, and in my **ClistView** i have some sortable attributes. Which works fine, problem is the test doesn't read from the `attributeLabels()` in my model class.

```
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
        'params'=> array(':lat' => $lat, ':lng'=>$lng, ':radius'=>$radius),
        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'distance ASC',
            'attributes'=>array(
                'store','state','distance'
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=> $perPage,
        ),
    )
);
```

I have to change it too below for it to work.

```
'attributes' => array(
    'store'=>'Store Name', 
    'state'=> 'State',
    'distance'=>'Distance to Store'
),
```

any idea what i'm missing?

here is my `attributeLabels()` in my model

```
public function attributeLabels(){
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'store' => 'Store Name',
        'address' => 'Address',
        'city' => 'City',
        'state' => 'State',
        'country' => 'Country',
        'descscription' => 'Description',
        'ip' => 'Ip',
        'distance'=>'Distance to Store'
    );
}
```

Here is my relations in `store.php` model for the `state` model

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            '_state' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'state', 'state'),
            '_contact' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'StoreContact', 'store_id'),
        );
    }
```

Comment: this is because you aren't working with your model. Can you please add the `$sql`. I think you can do this without a `CSqlDataProvider`.

Comment: @Dinistro updated question. also, my sort and pagination dont work when i use `CSqlDataProvider()` guess they are related

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't expect a query like this (very complex calculation). I think, that I'm not able to solve your problem today. I'm not having much time, sorry.

Comment: @Dinistro no worries. yeah thats why i thought i had to use `CSqlDataProvider` instead. Seemed like an easier solution. I'm kind of new to Yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge difference between `CActiveDataProvider` and `CSqlDataProvider`:

**[CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider)**

> CActiveDataProvider implements a data provider based on ActiveRecord.

**[CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)**

> CSqlDataProvider implements a data provider based on a plain SQL statement.

So, when you use `CSqlDataProvider`, model will have no role, and your data provider won't look for any model.

However, if you want to use your model attributes, you can use key-value array in your `CSqlDataProvider` and do like below:

```
'attributes' => array(
    'store'=> StoreModel::model()->getAttributeLabel('store'), 
    'state'=> StoreModel::model()->getAttributeLabel('state'),
    'distance'=> StoreModel::model()->getAttributeLabel('distance'),
),
```

Note that I assumed that your model's name is `StoreModel`

Comment: but using my `CSqlDataProvider` is still shows my pagination when my results are only 3. Pagination is set as 10